# in android how can i get the intent can translate data size

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

i want to use the intent to translat the bitmap to next Activity.but the bitmap sometimes is big and i want to compress the bimap to a right size.i found the different phone can translat data size is not the same.some phones use the intent can translat 2MB data but some phones can just translate 500kb data.so how can l get the intent translate data size in different phones.thanks

```
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 573440 bytes
```

Comment: A suggestion: Instead of passing translated bitmap, you can store that bitmap as image in memory and pass path for that image to next activity. And then in next activity you can again read and convert it to bitmap. Then you don't need to take care of different data sizes

Comment: intent is not designed to pass large data size. Save your data to file and pass a file path in the intent.

Comment: thanks.but i translate to the third app.

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko thanks.but i translate to the third app. so have another way?

Comment: that depends on which app exactly. It the app is not your own, then if it supposed to work with images, it has to have API for that.

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko yes,i use third Api to share the image,but they not get the big image share way.

Comment: I think they should have. Maybe you just don't know this way? But I can't help you since you are hiding the details.

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko thanks again.i will quest to they.